# How to test if OS version is greater than Windows XP SP2

Tags: .net, asp.net

Hi there I am writing a piece of code where I want to make sure that the code is onle executed on the machine in which OS is WindowsXPSP2 or greater. I have got OS version of the OS ex- 5.1,5.2 and so on.

I just want to know how can I make sure that the OS is either WindowsXPSP2 or greater?
Can I check it with version number > 5.1?

Comment: Check if it's Vista.  If so, then it is lesser than Windows XP SP2.  :-)

Comment: why is this tagged asp.net? Are you doing this in a web application?

Answer (score 2):

Try that :

```
Version versionXPSP2 = new Version(5,2);
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= versionXPSP2)
{
    // this is XP SP2 or higher
}
```

(not tested)

**EDIT:**
The code above actually doesn't work... here is another one :

```
Version version = Environment.OSVersion
if (version.Major > 5 || (version.Major == 5 && version.Minor >= 1 && version.ServicePack >= "Service Pack 2"))
{
    // this is XP SP2 or higher
}
```

Comment: he's looking for SP2, not SP3

Comment: uh, sorry, bad copy/paste... will fix

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can query the service pack string using

```
Environment.OSVersion.ServicePack
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use version 5 and the OperatingSystem.ServicePack property:

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
if (os.Version.Major > 5 || (os.Version.Major == 5 && os.Version.Minor >= 1 && Int32.Parse(os.ServicePack.Replace("Service Pack ", "")) >= 2))
{

}
else
{
    throw new Exception("OS not supported.");
}
```

I couldn't test it, it's based on Thomas' version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx).

I believe XP is Major version 5, Minor version 1.  You might also want to check the Platform property to make sure it's running on the OS type you think it's running on (i.e. NOT Mac, Unix, WinCE, Xbox, etc.).